# How to append two NSMutableArray's in Iphone sdk or append an NSArray With NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c

I need to append two NSMUtableArray's can any one suggest me how it possible?

My code is:

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [appDelegate getTextList:1];
NSArray *array2 = [appDelegate getTextList:2];
[array1 addObjectsFromArray:array2];//I am getting exception here.
```

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thanks all,
Lakshmi.

Comment: What's the exception you are getting?

Comment: This is the exception I am getting:

Comment: 2010-09-28 14:18:10.685 VoiceMessenger[3147:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x166090> was mutated while being enumerated.(
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17b200>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17b370>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17c090>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17b260>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17cb20>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17d120>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17d710>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17dd40>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17e320>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17e950>",
    "<TextMsgObj: 0x17b200>"
)'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's probably happening, is that your [appDelegate getTestList:1] is not actually returning a `NSMutableArray`, but a `NSArray`. Just typecasting the array as mutable by holding a pointer to it like that will not work in that case, instead use:

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[appDelegate getTextList:1] mutableCopy];
NSArray *array2 = [appDelegate getTextList:2];
[array1 addObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

Or you could store the 'textList' variable that you have in your appDelegate as an NSMutableArray in the first place. I am assuming that you have an `NSArray` of `NSArrays` (or their mutable versions). Eg.

```
// In the class interface
NSMutableArray *textLists;

// In the function in which you add lists to the array
NSMutableArray *newTextList;
[self populateArray:newTextList]; // Or something like that

[textLists addObject:newTextList];
```

**Note:** that you will probably have a different workflow, but I hope that you get the idea of storing the actual lists as NSMutableArrays.

**Another Note:** the second method ***WILL*** modify in place the `NSMutableArray` that  `[appDelegate getTextList:1];` returns

Comment: Actually I am getting the list from Xmlparser and I am stoting it in the NSMutableArray like: NSMutableArray *array1 = [appDelegate getTextList:1];

Comment: Actually My problem is At first time I will get 10 items from the parser and I store it in NSMutableArray *textArrayList; I will use this array through out the controller.when I hit load more resuts buttons I am sending the parameter of pagenumber and again getting next ten more items.I want this next ten items to append to the textArrayList.And display all the 20 items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *result = 
    [[appDelegate getTextList:1] mutableCopy] 
        addObjectsFromArray:[appDelegate getTextList:2]];
```

You're getting the exception because you're trying to send mutating messages to an immutable array.